# Count of all element less than the value in a row

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Given a dataframe

```
value
-----
0.3
0.2
0.7
0.5
```

is there a way to build a column that contains, for each row, the count of the element in that row that are less or equal than the row value? Specifically,

```
value   count_less_equal
-------------------------
0.3     2
0.2     1
0.7     4
0.5     3
```

I could groupBy the value column but I don't know how to filter all values in the row that are less that that value.

I was thinking, maybe it's possible to duplicate the first column, then create a filter so that for each value in `col1` one finds the count of values in `col2` that are less than `col1` value.

```
col1   col2
-------------------------
0.3     0.3
0.2     0.2
0.7     0.7
0.5     0.5
```

Comment: Isn't that what `dense_rank()` does?

Comment: salting with self_join n then groupby count should be the way to go. in spark3.0+ u can use skew join (on self join) instead of salting

Answer (score 2):

you can use self join and perform join on `t1.user_id>=t2.user_id` to get the desired result.

```
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

    spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .appName('SO')\
        .getOrCreate()

    sc= spark.sparkContext

    df = sc.parallelize([
        ([0.3]), ([0.2]), ([0.7]), ([0.5])

    ]).toDF(["value"])

    df.show()

    # +-------+
    # |user_id|
    # +-------+
    # |    0.3|
    # |    0.2|
    # |    0.7|
    # |    0.5|
    # +-------+


    df.createTempView("table")

    spark.sql('select t1.value, count(*) as count from table t1 join table t2 on t1.value>=t2.value  group by t1.value order by value').show()

    # +-----+-----+
    # |value|count|
    # +-----+-----+
    # |  0.2|    1|
    # |  0.3|    2|
    # |  0.5|    3|
    # |  0.7|    4|
    # +-----+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks, I like your suggestion. The only drawback is that it's quite slow

Answer (score 1):

You can sort them and count the unique values below them using window function

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window
tst= sqlContext.createDataFrame(
[
(1,0.3),
(2,0.2),
(3,0.7),
(4,0.5),
(5,0.5),
(3,0.7),
(6,1.0),
(9,0.4)
],schema=['id','val'])
w=Window.orderBy('val') # consider adding a partition column here; If none consider salting
tst1 = tst.withColumn("result",F.size((F.collect_set('val')).over(w)))

tst1.show()
+---+---+------+
| id|val|result|
+---+---+------+
|  2|0.2|     1|
|  1|0.3|     2|
|  9|0.4|     3|
|  5|0.5|     4|
|  4|0.5|     4|
|  3|0.7|     5|
|  3|0.7|     5|
|  6|1.0|     6|
+---+---+------+
```

Comment: Problem of window functions without partitioning is that they collect all data in a single partition. Indeed I receive the following warning: `WARN WindowExec: No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation`.

Comment: @Galuoises - I agree, will add it as a comment in the code. I didnt add it here, just as a toy example. You can also add a dummy key for partitioning known as salting techinque

Comment: I have edited the question, as I suspect that adding a second column with the same values it could help. Indeed this could use chunks of data instead of sorting all values

Comment: Thanks a lot, anyhow I think there might a be a problem with your solution. Indeed, even if it's right up to 0.4, for 0.5 it should give 5, for 0.7 it's 7 and for 1.0 I expect 8, as I am looking for all numbers less or equal than x

Comment: Moreover, even if I partition data, the window function will check the condition `<=` only inside the partition itself but not inside the other partitions.