# Spark Aggregating a single column based on several overlapping windows

Tags: apache-spark

Let's say I have the following table with money spent per day (timestamp)

```
timestamp| spent
0        | 0
1        | 0
2        | 1
3        | 4
4        | 0
5        | 0
6        | 1
7        | 3
```

The result I'm looking for is a table adding columns for the cummulative money spent in the last "n" days, for example the last 2 days and the last 5 days. Resulting in something like this.

```
timestamp  | spent | spent-2d  |spent-5d | ....
0          | 0     | null      | null    | ...
1          | 0     | 0         | null    | ...
2          | 1     | 1         | null    | ...
3          | 4     | 5         | null    | ...
4          | 0     | 4         | 5       | ...
5          | 0     | 0         | 5       | ...
6          | 1     | 1         | 6       | ...
7          | 3     | 4         | 8       | ....
```

One possible solution is to add lagged columns and then sum but for say, 180 days I would need to add 180 columns and I want to to this process with not just one but several columns in the dataframe. For example for 100-500 columns I want the lagged sum over 1,2,5,7,15,30,90 and 180 days. So adding 180*500 columns seems to be a bad idea.

Any other ideas to make this in a very efficient way?

Comment: I can't understand your expectation. If you need the information for various columns, it has to be introduced right?

Comment: This will require efforts but you can use the 2 day lag over 90day column to create 180d, similarly for 90 d use 30d and so on

Answer (score 0):

Window "rangeBetween" method can be used, example for 5 days column:

```
val lastFiveDaysWindow = Window
  .orderBy("timestamp")
  .rangeBetween(Window.currentRow - 4, Window.currentRow)

df
  .withColumn("spent-5d",
    when(
      $"timestamp" >= 4,
      sum("spent").over(lastFiveDaysWindow)
    )
  )
```

**Note:** Only for small Dataframes, warning exists:

> No Partition Defined for Window operation! Moving all data to a single partition, this can cause serious performance degradation.

For bigger DataFrames, inner join can be used, like in answer here:
[Count of all element less than the value in a row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63114467/count-of-all-element-less-than-the-value-in-a-row)